# Shopify: Set minimum quantity for a product using the Quantity Selector

Tags: input, shopify, minimum, product-quantity

Trying to see if there's a way on certain products in my clients Shopify store where for wholesale customers, they must order at least a quantity of 15 per item.

I'm trying a script to get the Quantity Selector to start at 15 instead of one but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
<quantity-input class="quantity">
    <button class="quantity__button no-js-hidden" name="minus" type="button">
        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.quantity.decrease' | t: product: product.title | escape }}</span>
            {% render 'icon-minus' %}
        </button>
            {% assign productTags = product.tags | join: ', ' %}
            {% if productTags contains 'wholesale' %}
            <input class="quantity__input"
                type="number"
                name="quantity"
                id="Quantity-{{ section.id }}"
                min="15"
                value="1"
                form="{{ product_form_id }}"
              >
              {% else %}
            <input class="quantity__input"
                type="number"
                name="quantity"
                id="Quantity-{{ section.id }}"
                min="1"
                value="1"
                form="{{ product_form_id }}"
              >
              {% endif %}
            <button class="quantity__button no-js-hidden" name="plus" type="button">
              <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.quantity.increase' | t: product: product.title | escape }}</span>
              {% render 'icon-plus' %}
          </button>
      </quantity-input>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your other conditions are working regarding the **wholesale** Tag logic, you also need to set the Value to Min Value (in this case 15) instead of 1. So your input field code for Wholesale products would become

```
<input class="quantity__input" type="number" name="quantity" id="Quantity-{{ section.id }}" min="15" value="15" form="{{ product_form_id }}">
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked even better than I had expected.